# Azure function and Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, azure

I have created an Azure function which is trigered when a new file is added to my Blob Storage. This part works well !
BUT, now I would like to start the "Speech-To-Text" Azure service using the API. So I try to create my URI leading to my new blob and then add it to the API call. To do so I created an SAS Token (From Azure Portal) and I add it to my new Blob Path .

```
https://myblobstorage...../my/new/blob.wav?[SAS Token generated]
```

By doing so I get an error which says :

```
Authentification failed Invalid URI
```

What am I missing here ?

N.B : When I generate manually the SAS token from the "Azure Storage Explorer" everything is working well. Plus my token is not expired in my test

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might generate the SAS token with wrong authentication.
Make sure the Object option is checked.
[image]

Here is the reason in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas?redirectedfrom=MSDN#specifying-account-sas-parameters):

> - Service (s): Access to service-level APIs (e.g., Get/Set Service Properties, Get Service Stats, List Containers/Queues/Tables/Shares)
> - Container (c): Access to container-level APIs (e.g., Create/Delete Container, Create/Delete Queue, Create/Delete Table, Create/Delete
>   Share, List Blobs/Files and Directories)
> - Object (o): Access to object-level APIs for blobs, queue messages, table entities, and files(e.g. Put Blob, Query Entity, Get Messages,
>   Create File, etc.)

Comment: Nope it still fails with the same error ... Is it possible that a function does not have the right to access it ? Indeed it is working when I copy/Paste the link in my browser but the function fails ...

Comment: Now it's not the SAS token's problem, it's another question. Could you please accept my answer and ask another question about why function don't work with SAS token contains your function code?